# What's the best way to make a text file available to a web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a JavaScript Hangman game. I'm not sure how to go about making the text file containing the possible words available to the application so that everyone who uses the app starts with the same word bank. How is this typically done?

Comment: You need a web server.

Comment: Are you using nodejs? can you be more specific?

Answer (score -1):

You can save your text file with your Project files and just add this line in to your code 
Rules for a Game